# How to return entity after insert it in generic repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using entity framework and wrote a generic repository to implement the UnitOfWork pattern.

I need to return the entity I inserted, with the assigned id.

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal AppDb Context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    public GenericRepository(AppDb context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    // ...

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
         DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think `DbSet<TEntity>.Add` already returns the entity have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679587(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
public virtual TEntity Insert(TEntity entity)
{
     return DbSet.Add(entity);
}
```

[`DbSet<T>.Add()` returns `T`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679587(v=vs.113).aspx), so just change the return type and type `return`.

Comment: so i don't need to save to get the new id

Comment: Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't expand your questions by commenting on answers, make sure your question contains everything we and you need to know. Of course you need to call `DbContext.SaveChanges()`, otherwise the entity won't have the database generated ID assigned. Whether you want to call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` in your generic repository's `Insert()` method is entirely up to you. If you want `Insert()` to return an entity that has been saved to the database, yes, you have to call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` before returning.

Comment: @Terry when a site gets thousands of questions a day, many of those so unclear they can't be answered without additional information by the OP, it becomes mandatory to read some text before you can ask a question. This is not a forum with a handful of friends, it's a vast community with hundreds of thousands of members and millions of questions.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't think it is mandatory. It is useful, surely, for those who want to answer only the questions posed by those who meet their standards.

It just sets the stage for the site to become more and more about servicing an elite inside crowd that has risen in the ranks to the point that they can push others out.